# jwplayer ga pro2 not working for drupal module

Tags: drupal-7, google-analytics, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using https://drupal.org/project/jw_player_gapro2 module, But Its looks like this module not sending any event to GA. I am using Drupal-7.24 and jw_player recommended version module.

any points?

Comment: Where is this running? I have never heard of this module before. We didn't make that.

Comment: Also the module that it recommends is not built by us either.

Comment: This module is on drupal.org. we supposed to use drupal community module, right? OR Should I download module from jwplayer site? Is there any on jwplayer site? I have pro account, so let me know How can I get it work with drupal, of course?

Comment: This is our official module for Drupal - https://drupal.org/project/jwplayermodule

Comment: this is not in drupal7. and It suggest for the module I am using. "For a Drupal 7 version, please try: http://drupal.org/project/jw_player"

Comment: The site is not public, so I can't share url. So Let me know the possible steps for this functionality in drupal-7 site. I have to show/play video and track them in GA.

Comment: I would need to see a link so I can see where it went wrong.

Comment: As I told site is not public, but I would try to setup another system. Till then I can tell you that when I play a video there is a request going from system "http://i.n.jwpltx.com/v1/jwplayer6/ping.gif?tv=3867&ph=0&n=6304221178870648&aid=3HZtskvKEeOrkSIACqoGtw&e=s&i=0&pv=6.5.3609&pu=<site_url>&m=1&a=0&v=0&w=640&h=360&mu=<file_url>&t=undefined&ed=1&pt=page title | site title". Is this something to do ?

Comment: That is for JW Player 6 Analytics. If you are using the GAPro-2 plugin, that is for JW Player 5 only. Adding GA to JW Player 6 is done like this - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28853/connecting-google-analytics

Comment: If I will add <code>ga : {}</code> in setup configuration, from where it would take GA-tracking-ID ? I have something like this in console
<code>
</code>

Comment: [continue to above comment]

If I will add "ga : {}" in setup configuration, from where it would take GA-tracking-ID ? I have something like this in console
http://codepad.org/ThWIZgca

Is this right format ? or I just have to add "ga : {}" to setup ?

Comment: I have tried three options from my localhost.

1. http://postimg.org/image/xcbwkd9wj/
2. http://postimg.org/image/kilahradf/
3. http://postimg.org/image/pcu6rmvvr/

and I don't have any js error in console. please advice what am I missing ?

Comment: The ga tracking ID is loaded via an external GA <script> tag in the <head> of the page. If you are using JW6 though, you need the premium edition of the player in order for GA Analytics to work.

Comment: I have pro account, I have bought it to remove jwplayer logo on player. Will that account work ? And Which one is correct format for adding ga in setup(); from my last comment ?

Comment: The ga: {} is correct. The tracking code is supposed to be in the <head> of your page in the <script> tag provided by Google. From this guide - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28853/connecting-google-analytics, "This guide explains how to enable and use the built-in Google Analytics integration with the JW Player. It is available only in the Premium and Ads editions of JW Player 6."

Comment: I have added ga:{} to code, but this is not showing in googla analytics. I have file download tracking, which is working real time. But WHen I play a video there is nothing in events in GA. You can check on this page http://www.crazyrohila.com/video-test/

Comment: Or is does not work in real time ?

Comment: And I can see my reports on jw_player site's analyze page. So please advice why is this not recording in GA ?

Comment: Do you have a JW6 Premium account? Because, Premium and up are the only editions that support GA.

Comment: When you right click on video, it will show player version and I have pro account. I have 6.5.3609 (pro edition).

Comment: you can see code in source of page, and I posted here too, http://codepad.org/jGxeBhQy

Comment: Pro accounts do not have access to GA. It is a Premium+ feature only. It says so in our documentation - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28853/connecting-google-analytics - "This guide explains how to enable and use the built-in Google Analytics integration with the JW Player. It is available only in the Premium and Ads editions of JW Player 6."

Comment: Thanks man! I was thinking there is only two edition, free and pro. Now Its working. Thanks again :)